# Basis for field extension of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. Let $f_p : \mathbb{F}_{p^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ be the Frobenius map ($f(a) = a^p$). I want to find a characteristic polynomial of $f_p.$

I think $A = \{1, p, p^2, ..., p^{n-1}\}$ is a $\mathbb{F}_p-$basis of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Since $$\mbox{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p) = <f_p> \simeq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},$$ $f_p$ fixes elements in $\mathbb{F}_p.$

So $f_p(1) = 1, f_p(p) = p, ..., f_p(p^{n-1}) = p^{n-1}$ (using $f(p) = p $ and $f$ is a linear map). So the characteristic polynomial is $(1-t)^n.$

But I saw here https://books.google.com/books?id=lrMOjbLhR2IC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=diagonalizable+over+Fq+if+n+divides+p-1&source=bl&ots=jpC-9d3oWJ&sig=sc2D6D5igoLw5LRHTWWRf9qP7_E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ3pLjzbDbAhVSHjQIHYV8CcgQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=diagonalizable%20over%20Fq%20if%20n%20divides%20p-1&f=false (page 9)

that minimal polynomial is $t^n - 1.$ (I guess it is the characteristic polynomial as well)

So my attempt is wrong ?

The argument used in the book involves normal basis theorem which I have never seen/proved before. Is there a way to build a basis and calculate the characteristic polynomial directly ?

Besides direct computational, is there a way to find a characteristic polynomail ?

If the vector space $V$ is of dimensional $n$, and a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ satisfying

(1) $p(f_p) = 0$

(2) deg$(p) = n =$dim$V$

(3) $p$ or $-p$ is monic

Is it possible to conclude that $p$ is the characteristic polynomail ?

Comment: $\{1,p,p^2,\ldots, p^{n-1}\}$ is not a basis for $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. You need to take an irreducible polynomial  $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of degree $n$ and then you can synthetically add in a root of this polynomial $\omega$ such that $f(\omega)=0$ then $\{1,\omega, \ldots, \omega^{n-1}\}$ is a basis.

Comment: For example $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$ add in $\omega$ with the property that $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ that is $\omega^2=\omega+1$ and $\mathbb{F}_4 \cong \mathbb{F}_2[\omega]$. Of course different choices of irreducible polynomials result in slightly different isomorphic versions of the fields. There is a standard choice for any $p$ and $n$, The conway polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polynomial_(finite_fields)

Comment: Note that $p^k=0 $ in $\mathbb {F}_p $ for all $k\geq1$. So it is definitely not a basis.